# Visual Studio throwing compilation errors for commented out code

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio is throwing strange errors when I try to compile a project.

Errors:

Remove commented out code 
Remove unused private members

Previously I was able to build the project successfully with the same code base.

Comment: Just to be sure: these are really *errors* that block running your application and not *suggestions* that give squiggly lines but still allow you to run it?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a combination of:

a) some sort of code analyzer (StyleCop maybe), and
b) "treat warnings as errors" (see build tab of the project's properties).

Try "////" (4 slashes) to comment out the code. That is a suggestion that StyleCop itself gives when you really want to (temporarily) have commenented-out code.

Before you switch off "treat warnings as errors", see why that was switched on: if company rules and/or team rules require this, then discuss with company and/or team what to do. Of course this assumes that this work is done for a company and/or in a team.